# Приложение после компиляции через cx freeze запускается с консолью

Tags: python, pyqt4

Приложение с графическим интерфейсом (PyQt4) после компиляции через cx freeze открывается с консолью. Самое интересное, что программка у меня в формате .pyw и, когда я её запускаю в этом формате, она открывается без консоли. А после компиляции с консолью! Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880316/hide-console-window-with-wxpython-and-cxfreeze) есть ответ. Но по моему личному мнение, делать "якобы exe" с питоном - кощунство.

Comment: нужно дщоабвить base = 'Win32GUI'?

Comment: да, в командную строку. только не забудьте два минуса перед ней:)

Comment: а если я компилирую через файлик setup.py? то как?

Comment: Вам нужен результат или шашечки?