# Как красиво запустить программу на Python: как убрать окно командной строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Не знаю как по другому сформулировать вопрос.
Я пишу программку. И тут я решил попробовать запустить ее на других компьютерах. И при запуске (двойной клик по главному файлу) Открывается программа и все хорошо, Но на фоне остается окно командной строки + хотелось бы как нибудь вставить иконку программы на панели пуск.[image]
Главное подскажите как убрать окно командной строки. Мне нужен запуск по двойному клику, не обязательно по .exe
Неужели обязательно упаковывать cx_freeze?

Comment: Может тоже пригодится: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/65617

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для винды достаточно поменять расширение файла `.py` на `.pyw` — такие файлы запускаются без окна командной строки.

Comment: А вы не подскажите если я упакую в .exe это не замедлит выполнение программы?

Comment: Вот про .exe лично я ничего не знаю, но могу предложить измерить самостоятельно)

Comment: Надо бы заняться ))

Comment: Подскажите как провернуть тоже самое используя cx_Freeze у меня это не сработало хоть я и изменил форматы файлов перед обработкой.

Answer (score 0):

чтоб сделать .exe установите модуль pyinstaller и пишите pyinstaller -F имя файла.pyw

Comment: Извините, но в вопросе не спрашивается как сделать .exe. Не могли бы вы изменить ваше сообщение так, чтобы оно прямо отвечало на вопрос ТС.